# 'CroppedFile?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File', Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, file, dart, crop

After using the Image Cropper plugin in flutter, I want to convert the image to type File to be able to display it in the next screen. I am unable to figure a way to display the Cropped Image. Can I get some help with this?

Comment: Can you provide your source code to better help your problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just create a new File like this

```
final File imageFile = File(croppedFile.path);
```

I guess you could also do the same thing reading the bytes but I don't think there is any difference and this seems more straight forward